# Error in using of file_get_contents to download large files

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

When i use file_get_contents with $offset != -1 returns false
The file i want to get from a URL is very large.
Is it possible to use offset parameter with non local file?

The code that i use it:

```
 $content = file_get_contents($encodedurl,false,NULL,$offset,$blocksize);
```

Comment: What does mean "Very large"? 19kb? 32MB? 18GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) says:

> Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files. Attempting to seek on non-local files 
>   may work with small offsets, but this is unpredictable because it
>   works on the buffered stream.

If your file is very large, then I think your best bet would be to write your own function which simulates a HTTP GET request to the resource. You can then read the file in on a buffered basis, that way you can store, say 16MB, chunks of the file onto disk, and once it has been fully downloaded you can always recombine this into one file. Or process it as chunks as required.